# MockK - Are multiple calls to verify() with different "exact =" in the same test supported?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

I have strange behaviour. I have a unit-test that does some stuff and then performs the following verification statements:

```
    verify(exactly = 2) {
        observer.onThingChanged()
    }
    verify(exactly = 1) {
        b.addThing(thing)
    }
    verify(exactly = 0) {
        observer.onAnotherThingChanged(any())
    }
```

This test fails on the **second** call to `verify()` with the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: Observer(#2).onThingChanged()).
2 matching calls found, but needs at least 1 and at most 1 calls
Calls:
1) Observer(#2).onThingChanged()
2) Observer(#2).onThingChanged()
```

This makes no sense. It seems to be using the "exactly" parameter from the **second** `verify()` call, but the code block from the **first** `verify()` call.

Am I missing something? Are multiple calls to `verify()` with different `exactly=` arguments supported?

Comment: it is indeed very weird. the scenario that you are going is totally supported - I just tried here without a problem.
Can you post your entire method instead of only the verify calls?
Also, if you change anything? Does it work? Like, changing everything to exactly = 2 (obvisouly it will break down the line, but will the first verify succeed?!

Comment: @HenriqueVasconcellos good to know that this is supported. By changing the values of the `exactly` parameters and setting breakpoints, I think I discovered what the problem is. The object `b` is a real object and not a mock object. It looks like you cannot verify method/function calls to real objects, only to mock objects. This was not clear to me. As soon as I changed `b` to be a mock object (and modified the rest of the test accordingly) everything worked as expected.

Comment: Glad that it worked! Exactly if you try to verify something that is not mocked, Mockk cannot "see" the object being called.

Comment: @HenriqueVasconcellos I understand that,but the error message that's given is completely wrong! It sent me on a wild goose chase! I would prefer an error saying "you can't verify actions on non-mocked objects!"